# Does MvvmCross rely on Google Play Services?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am considering using Xamarin.Android and MvvmCross on an enterprise device that does not have Google Play Services or any other Google apps/services (i.e. Google Maps).

Does MvvmCross have any dependencies on Google Play Services or other Google apps/services that may not exist on an enterprise device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only time you would need to install the Google Play Services component is if you use a feature like Maps, Cloud Messaging, or In-app purchases.

MvvmCross is very modular and you include only the features you need primarily via plugins.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Kiliman, MvvmCross has no dependencies on Google Play.

To get you started here are two good links:

1) [Writing a first App](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/566191/MvvmCross-v-Writing-a-First-App)

2) [Video on using MvvmCross and Android (iOS and Windows as well)](http://vimeo.com/68375201)